# XPages Multiline Edit Box validation fails on blank lines

Tags: validation, xpages, multiline

I'm getting a failure when attempting to validate required content for a Multiline Edit Box control.   I'm using simple required validation only, as follows:

```
<xp:inputTextarea
id="subject1"
rows="5"
style="width:99%"
value="${javascript:'#{compositeData.requestDocument.subject}'}"
multipleSeparator="#{javascript:@NewLine()}"
required="true">
<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateRequired
        message="Please explain the issue for which you need help." />
</xp:this.validators>
```

If I enter multiple lines WITHOUT blank lines the validation succeds:

"foo line 1
foo line 2
foo line 3"

but if I enter multiple lines WITH a blank line the validation fails:

"foo line 1

foo line 3"

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a really simple solution myself.  Don't know if this is the PROPER way to do it, but it seems to work.

I changed the validation from required to length  (xp:validateRequired vs. xp:validateLength) as follows:

```
<xp:inputTextarea
    id="subject1"
    rows="5"
    style="width:99%"
    value="${javascript:'#{compositeData.requestDocument.subject}'}"
    multipleSeparator="#{javascript:@NewLine()}">
    <xp:this.validators>

        <xp:validateLength
            message="Please explain the issue for which you need help."
            minimum="2">
        </xp:validateLength>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: After reviewing my code over the weekend I realized there was an even simpler solution.  I simply removed the multipleSeparator from the control.  Hard returns are stored in the field and displayed properly.  The code for this is: 

    <xp:inputTextarea
     id="subject1"
     rows="5"
     style="width:99%"
     required="true"
     value="#{document1.subject}">
     <xp:this.validators>
      <xp:validateRequired
       message="Please enter a subject."></xp:validateRequired>
     </xp:this.validators>
    </xp:inputTextarea>